# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 for static files

Tags: node.js, angular, nginx, deployment, cloudflare

I have been trying to deploy a stage web app(Angular/NodeJS) on AWS EC2. For the main app, let's say the URL is example.com, so for the stage site I am keeping it staging.example.com.

I deployed the main app on EC2, using nginx server and certbot for SSL. It works perfectly.

For stage site, I added the following to the Cloudflare DNS settings:
[image]

Deployed the same app on another EC2 using nginx and certbot for SSL, it all worked fine but after going to the URL, the index file is reachable but the static files are not.

This is the server code used to get the static files:

[image]

And this is the error I am getting in the console:

[image]

I have tried many solutions in the past few days but nothing worked, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What do you see when you try directly accessing the static file? Also, try clearing cache on Cloudflare.

Comment: It gives the same "404 Not Found" and clearing cache also didn't work.